# WV Polo 2011 petrol 1.2 engine chugging and loses power - engine, EPC, Tyre pressure light on

Tags: engine, vw, overheating, stall, gasoline

First time posting on a forum like this, and english is not my first language, so please be patient.

I know almost nothing about cars, I would ask people that I know do they think about certain things, which brought me to this problem now.

The Polo was overheated, meaning I revd the engine hard and black smoke came out as my cars went in emergency/limp mode. Since then they car was getting gradually worse. I brought it to a mechanic and he doesnt want to touch is anymore as he cant find the reason why is it doing this.

What I notice it, whenever its cold it would work normally for a bit and then it will start chugging/shacking and it wont go over 2000-3000rpm.

I am struggling to find any good mechanic or any service centre to have a look as they will only do basic stuff - changing oil, tyres, wipers, etc.

I am trying to gage wether this car is ready to be sold for parts or there is hope of fixing it and getting some of my money back eventually.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the check engine light on? If so, have you (or can you) checked to see what it says? How long after starting it cold does it go from running well until it starts running rough?